# Spreadsheet::ParseExcel

Tags: perl, spreadsheet

I am using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel, and want to take the file name as an input from the user. Moreover, I want the parsing of two files to happen based on a condition provided by the user.

This is what I wrote:

```
print("Enter the path of the file_y:");
$file_y=<STDIN>;
chomp($file_y);

print("Enter the path of the file_n:");
$file_n=<STDIN>;
chomp($file_n);

print("Enter whether file_y or file_n is required(y/n)?");
$yes=<STDIN>;
chomp($yes);

my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
if($yes eq "y")
{
    my $workbook = $parser->parse($file_y);
}
elsif($yes eq "n")
{
    my $workbook = $parser->parse($file_n);
}

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), "Worksheet not defined.\n";
```

It prints "Worksheet not defined" even though yes gets the values y or n.

Comment: Yes this relates more to Perl I guess... but I am working on a Linux based system, thus asked the question here.Moreover I could not post it on stack exchange as they asked me not to for 3 days.Sorry for the unappropriate question, if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `my` declares local variables. Therefore, `$workbook` is local to the body of the following `if`:

```
if($yes eq "y")
{
    my $workbook = 1;
}
```

You could get the scoping that you are looking for by declaring `$workbook` before the first `if`, as `my $workbook`, and then, inside the `if` or `elsif` blocks, assigning to it without declaring a new variable (`$workbook = $parser->parse ...`).

A few more things:

- I would recommend writing conditional code that makes it obvious that your variable is guaranteed to get assigned, so instead of `if (c) { $w = e } elsif (c') { $w = e' }`, I'd write `if (c) { $w = e } else { $w = e' }`.
- You can call perl as `perl -w` and add `use strict;` to receive better warnings about common mistakes; in particular, this forces you to declare every variable, and would have caught the fact that the `$workbook` in the last `if` clause had not been defined.
- It looks to me like this program would be better non-interactive: it could just take as a parameter the file name to use, rather than asking for two names and ignoring one.

Comment: Actually thie file_y and file_n are not the files present on my system.Actually the user can write his own excel file or can refer to one already there.Though I am able to refer to the file already there on the system , While reading the file created after taking user inputs in the program , result in the following error "Excel data not found" though both have the same extension .xls and the file format too is the same for both the files.(Microsoft Excel 97-2003).I thought I would require SPREADSHEET::XLSX, but it can read one file , so should read both.